# 500 (Internal Server Error) in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Please help.  I have this jQuery code

```
 $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var serializedData = $(".form-horizontal").serialize();  
    var criscore = new Array();            
    $('input[name^=criscore]').each(function(){
        criscore.push({score:$(this).val(), criid:$(this).data('criid')});
    });
     for (var key in criscore) {    
        var score = criscore[key].score;
        var criid = criscore[key].criid;
             //console.log(score +" s "+ criid);

             $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/judges/candidates/scorecandidates',
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    data: {
                        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                        'canId': $('input[name=canId]').val(),
                        'catId': $('input[name=catId]').val(),
                        'criId': criid,
                        'score': score,
                        'judgeId': $('input[name=judgeId]').val()
                        },
                    success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    }
                });
     }       

  });
```

and in my controller is

```
public function scorecandidates(Request $req)
{
    $data = new Score();
    $data->canId = $req->canId;
    $data->catId = $req->catId;
    $data->criId = $req->criId;
    $data->score = $req->score;
    $data->judgeId = $req->judgeId;
    $data->save();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

my problem is that it is still keeps having an 500 (Internal Server Error)

Even though I already put the csrf token is different ways.. Can any body help me?

Thank you

Comment: Change getting data. like this $req->input("canId"); in controller

Comment: @jonggu still the same :( internal server error

Comment: Could you post the error message? Is a TokenMismatchException? A dump of the `$req` would be useful aswell.

Comment: @EasyWay can you print any string in function first line?

Comment: Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/judges/candidates/scorecandidates
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: yes I can print, but when I do the saving code it displays the error, even if I already put the csrf tokens same as to my other codes..

Comment: Do you get error when save code? table schema is correct?

Comment: I think you should enable `error_reporting` and `display_erros` on your php configuration. It's very usefull to see the full error stack trace. Getting just `500 Internal Server` means your php error reporting is disabled.

Comment: Change `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file to see full error details.

Comment: @NirajShah Thanks